# MySql Full text Search

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

In my Job listings site, I need to show jobs which have similar titles to the one which is being viewed. I am trying the following query, but its not working:

```
SELECT  *, 
MATCH(title) AGAINST "Sales Coordinator" as relevance
FROM
  jobs
WHERE
  MATCH(title) AGAINST "Sales Coordinator"
ORDER BY relevance DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Also, can this be optimized, so as to give better results and maybe faster too?

Comment: 'it's not working'  How not working?  Error message?  No results?  Wrong results?  More infomation please.

Comment: And what's with the `enter code here` field in the SELECT?  Have you created the FULLTEXT index on the title field?

Comment: What is not working? And what is a "better result"? Can you show your table structure?

Answer (score 2):

You really need to clarify what is not working (i.e. what is it not finding) and how fast the current is. I assume you created a full text index on the "title" field?

You might be looking for the "IN BOOLEAN MODE" option.

```
MATCH(title) AGAINST ("Sales* Coordinator*" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

That would find things like "salesman".