# MySQL - Finding partial strings - Full Text?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I just found a bunch of rogue data in my MYSQL db...

The only way to get to it is via one of the columns - `FILE_PATH` which contains a slash stripped version of a file path. There are a few rogue files in this set that I need find - they all have the file name "Thumbs.db" but they have a variety of paths

example:

F:DatasetGroupedByFormatsx-fmt-398Thumbs.db

I have a full text index on the field, however the following query doesn't give any returns:

```
SELECT * FROM main_small WHERE MATCH `FILE_PATH` AGAINST  ('Thumbs.db')
```

Response:

```
MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0382 sec )
```

I am unsure whether this is because I have the syntax wrong, or whether the text string needs to be isolated by whitespace/punctuation.

Comment: Your full text query might work if you use ('"Thumbs.db"') (enclose yr phrase in double quotes), but this will also find 'thumbs db' (without the .)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Surely it's

```
select * from main_small where FILE_PATH like '%Thumbs.db'
```

However, if not then does [MySql Full text Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219058/mysql-full-text-search) help?

Comment: Surely indeed. Thanks. I didn't know the wildcard works on full text matching. That's really useful to know. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your query thinks 'Thumbs.db' is a whole word.  You'll need to find some way to do wildcard searching in order to select those rows.  How about:

```
SELECT * FROM main_small WHERE `FILE_PATH` LIKE '%Thumbs.db'
```

Comment: Thanks - this is correct - I have learnt something new today.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT * FROM main_small WHERE `FILE_PATH` LIKE '%Thumbs.db'
```

Comment: Thank you, this is of course correct. I didn't realise the % could be used like that.